# Nesting scaffolds in flutter to implement a slider

Tags: flutter

I'd like to use a custom slider instead of Material Design drawer.

The default drawer does not occupy any space in the scaffold and is pushed over the layout. I want a NavBar just like the desktop version of [this site.](https://angular.io/start)

Therefore, I nested a scaffold inside another one to make navigation possible inside the inner scaffold.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var show = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Multi Scaffold',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                show = !show;
              });
            },
          ),
          title: const Text("App"),
        ),
        body: InsideWidget(show: show),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InsideWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const InsideWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.show,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool show;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Row(
      children: [
        show
            ? SizedBox(
                width: 0.2 * w,
                height: h,
                child: Drawer(
                    child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                    )
                  ]),
                  child: ListView(
                    children: const [
                      DrawerHeader(child: Text("Iman")),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                        title: Text("Home"),
                      ),
                      Divider(),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.vertical_distribute_rounded),
                        title: Text("Home3"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
              )
            : Container(),
        SizedBox(
          width: show ? 0.8 * w : w,
          height: h,
          child: const Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
              body:
                  SizedBox(width: 100, child: Center(child: Text("Content")))),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As of Flutter docs, nesting scaffolds is not recommended.

I wonder if this is the best practice or whether a better way to implement this behaviour exists or not.

Comment: Instead of a nested Scaffold, you can use a Containers/SizedBoxes inside Scaffold. [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) is like a whole structure of a screen and nesting it is not recommended.

Comment: @immadisairaj then I think I should implement my own routing system. because I can not use the Flutter built-in routing.

Comment: I guess you can do that. In the content container, you can use different widgets to show the content. You can have it similar to navigation tabs. But, if you want to have back option too, you can store them inside the stack and use [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to go back in pages/widgets.